# What is the best way to merge XSD schemas?

Tags: xml, merge, xsd

Once a month I need to merge provider's XSD schema file with my version of the same schema. My version has annotations and possibly different order of root definitions and attribute definitions.

So far I have done it manually. Schema is huge, so this is painful.

Any ideas how to automate it?

Plain text/xml merging wont work due to ordering issues.

I have found no tools capable of doing this. Altova DiffDog lacks ability of merging xsd schemas.

At the moment I am thinking of either XQuery of just Powershell script.

Comment: Use XSLT.  XSDs are XML, and XSLT is the best way to transform XML.

Comment: You might re-think this altogether.  Why merge at all?  Just use the provider's schema, and if you have additional validation, keep that in a separate 2nd schema.  Just a thought...

Comment: I am generating code from that merged schema. I do not like code without comments which are normally generated from annotations.

Comment: Maybe you add your comments in your code generator instead of the source XSD to provide some isolation from partner changes?   Seems more practical than merging IMHO.  In any case, good luck, hope someone here on SO can provide a merging solution.